# mongodb / mongoose - sort by two fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two fields:

- date (`ISODate`)
- value (it's a `number` - however can be also `undefined`)

---

I want to sort them in a specific way.

**Firstly** - sort by `value`. If **it exists** (not `undefined`), let them come first. If `value` is undefined, push these objects at the end.

**Secondly** - sort by `date`. So at this moment, we will have everything sorted by `value`. But now I want to sort it by `date`.

### Expected result:

```
[
   {
      value: 1, 
      date: today, // ofc it's a date but just to represent the case
   }, 
   {
      value: 2,
      date: yesterday,
   },
   {
      value: undefined,
      date: today,
   },
   {
      value: undefined,
      date: yesterday,
   }
]
```

### Current solution:

```
.sort({
  value: -1,
  date: -1
});
```

However it fails in some situations, unfortunately Im unable to detect why it sometimes sort it in a wrong way. But it does...

Thank you in advance

Comment: Saying "it fails in some ways" is vague and unhelpful. What's the expected behavior and what are you seeing instead? Please describe and provide a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

> To achieving this you can use `aggregate` with `$cond`.

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').aggregate([
{
   $project :
       {
           "id" : 1,
           "value" : 1,
           "date": 1,
           sortValue: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $eq: ['$value',undefined ]},
              then: 0, 
              else: 1,
            },
          }
       }
},
{
   $sort :
       {
           "sortValue" :-1,
           "value" : 1,
           "date" : -1
       }
}])
```

> Tested in Mongo GUI.

**Aggregate In Mongoose:**

```
Model.aggregate([
  {
    $project:
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": 1,
      "date": 1,
      sortValue: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $eq: ['$value', undefined] },
          then: 0,
          else: 1,
        },
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort:
    {
      "sortValue": -1,
      "value": 1,
      "date": -1
    }
  }
], function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: How to use it with mongoose?